# how to get jquery compare operator working

Tags: jquery

```
  //check if the password mataches the password confirmation
    var passMatch = $('input[name="password"]');
    var passConfirm = $('input[name="confirm_password"]');
        passConfirm.on('blur',function(e) {
            console.log(passMatch.val());
            console.log(passConfirm.val());
            if(passMatch == passConfirm) {
                passConfirm.css({backgroundColor: 'lightgreen'});
                
            }else {
                passConfirm.addClass('error_message');
            }       
        })
```

I could be missing something here - (ok, I'm prob missing something there) but on blur BOTH these fields console.log the same value yet it applies the error_message class as if they didn't? I've tried !=, ==, ===, !== they all resort to the same - why?

Comment: You're comparing the elements, not their values. Take a look at the difference between your `console.log` lines and the `if` line.

Comment: WOW - thanks sorry been a long day!

Answer (score 1):

Even if the elements have the same values, their `==` comparison will be `false` as they are different DOM elements. To compare values use the same `val()` functions that you used in the printouts.

```
var passMatch = $('input[name="password"]');
var passConfirm = $('input[name="confirm_password"]');
passConfirm.on('blur',function(e) {
    if(passMatch.val() == passConfirm.val()) {
        passConfirm.css({backgroundColor: 'lightgreen'});
        passConfirm.removeClass('error_message');
    } else {
        passConfirm.addClass('error_message');
    }
})
```

Comment: I was going to give your same answer, you know? however there is a small bug in your code: the "error_message" class is not removed if the two passwords match .. :)

Comment: @Pinguto - nice catch. didn't look for other issues in the code. And it's not a bug in my code, but in OP's :D

Comment: If we really want to be picky, the same goes for the green background if the two fields coincide: the background, being declared directly on the element, becomes difficult to remove by applying a class to it .. :)

Comment: That's another fight for the OP, I guess. I'm not really concentrating on other bits of code - only the one that produces his man error :)

Comment: I understand .. :) A little curiosity .. what does OP mean? XD

Comment: That's Original poster or Author of the post.